# Array Push in Laravel 123

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to push new array item into existing array variable that has items from database. What I want to do is add a new item named 'Others' at the end of this array and display it as select drop down in view which consists of all the items from database and at the end of this select the 'Others' item that I manually added in my controller.

Here is what I tried to do:

[image]

Comment: get value from DB and create custom array, then use array_push($arr,'Others');

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Comment: i understan, i changed, but faild

Answer (score 1):

When you query from `database` in `Laravel`, the result is a `collection object`. You will first need to convert this `collection object` to `array` to be able to use array functions. The following should work in your case:

```
$admin = DB::table('tbl_account_admin')->where('id', $id)->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode(json_encode($admin), true);

And then use array_push function

Comment: Why go through multiple expensive functions just to convert the `collection` to `array`?

Comment: Becase, sometime toAray() will convert (if mix Query\Builder and Eloquent\Collection) -> array contains object